# Find the nth character of an increasing sequence

Tags: python, algorithm, math, data-structures, logic

Recently i saw a competitive coding question, the bruteforce approach doesn't meet the time complexity, Is there any other solution for this,

Question:

An expanding sequence is give which starts with 'a',we should replace each character in the following way,

a=>ab

b=>cd

c=>cd

d=>ab

there for it will look like this in each iteration,

a

ab

abcd

abcdcdab

abcdcdabcdababcd

.......
a number n will be given as input ,the function should return the character at nth postion.

[image]

[image]
[image]

I have tried the brute force approach by forming the full string and returning the char at n.but time limit exceeded.

i have tried the following:

```
dictionary={
    'a':'ab',
    'b':'cd',
    'c':'cd',
    'd':'ab'
}

string="a"

n=128
while len(string)<n:
    new_string=''
    for i in string:
        new_string+=dictionary[i]
    string=new_string
print(string[n-1])
```

Comment: Don't use `+=` to repeatedly concatenate strings. It's inefficient. Instead, use `''.join`. For instance, `n = 128; s = 'a'; while len(s) <= n: s = ''.join(dictionary[i] for i in s)`

Comment: Since the N can have a value of 2^63 you don't want to brute force this question. Print to the console the string of some reasonable length (say 100) and look for patterns. I'm sure that the string repeats itself from a certain position, so finding the character at position n will be O(1).

Comment: I think your solution is not even correct as it is. Try it with `n = 17` as the example says.

Comment: you mention "replace" but you did only in the 1st step, a --> ab, afterwards you just append... not clear

Comment: Have you noticed anything about how the length of the string increases with each iteration? Can you calculate -- cheaply -- the position of the desired character in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to problems like this is never to actually generate all the strings.

Here's a fast solution that descends directly through the tree of substitutions:

```py
dictionary={
    'a':['a','b'],
    'b':['c','d'],
    'c':['c','d'],
    'd':['a','b']
}

def nth_char(n):
    # Determine how many levels of substitution are reqired
    # to produce the nth character.
    # Remember the size of the last level
    levels = 1
    totalchars = 1
    lastlevelsize = 1
    while totalchars < n:
        levels += 1
        lastlevelsize *= 2
        totalchars += lastlevelsize
        
    # position of the target char in the last level
    pos = (n-1) - (totalchars - lastlevelsize)
    
    # start at char 1, and find the path to the target char
    # through the levels
    current = 'a'
    while levels > 1:
        levels -= 1
        # next iteration, we'll go to the left or right subtree
        totalchars -= lastlevelsize
        # half of the last level size is the last level size in the next iteration
        lastlevelsize = lastlevelsize//2
        # is the target char a child of the left or right subtitution product?
        # each corresponds to a contiguous part of the last level
        if pos < lastlevelsize:
            #left - take the left part of the last level
            current = dictionary[current][0]
        else:
            #right - take the right part of the last level
            current = dictionary[current][1]
            pos -= lastlevelsize

    return current
    
print(nth_char(17))
```